# Spilt one email into multiple jobids

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, jobid

So I have a weekly email, that has some conditional content based on the subscriber. Instead of making 5 different emails, I've done some Ampscript to split out the content based on the subscriber.

Problem is the JOBID is the same for all. Is there a way to change the JOBID based off of the content, event if its one send.

I wouldn't care, but analytics wants different JOBIDs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to set the JobID.  It's a system variable.

You can pass whatever variables you want in the [**Web Analytics Connector**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) , so if you set an AMPScript variable that represented the subscriber-specific content, it'll get passed along.

You can also write subscriber-specific content to the [**Send Log**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/) and extract it on an interval.